# Converting int to string

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, object

I'm having hard time understanding this. I've made a bottle objects and I have the weight of total bottle objects. But I'm trying to specify only one kind of bottle which is "Cola Cola". But, I know how to go through the list I've made and count the total weight. But if I want to only count the "Coca Cola" objects, I get lost. Any help?

---

```
class Flaske
{
    public String name = "Coca Cola";
    public int weight = 14;

    public Bottles(String na, int ve)
    {
         name = na;
         weight = ve;
    }
}
     //Total Bottle Weight
    public int findCocaColaWeight(Flaske[] kasse)
    {
            int result = 0;                
            int i = 0;
            while (i < kasse.Length)
            {
                if (kasse[i] != null)
                {
                    result = result + kasse[i].Weight.Equals("Coca Cola");
                }
                i = i + 1;
            }
            return result;            
    }
    //Find Coca Cola Weight
    public int findCocaColaWeight(Flaske[] kasse)
    {
            int result = 0;                
            int i = 0;
            while (i < kasse.Length)
            {
                if (kasse[i] != null)
                {
                    result = result + kasse[i].Weight;
                }
                i = i + 1;
            }
            return result;            
    }
```

So basically, I just need to know how to count only specific objects when I run into them, right?

Comment: The title of your post, and the text within it do not seem to be related.  What exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: how can `weight equal Coca Cola` if weight is an `Int` perhaps you are looking to use `Enum` learn to debug the code and understand the error messages / warnings

Comment: Why does the constructor of class Flaske is called Bottles???

Comment: @MethodMan, I said, im a noob. want to count the weight with only Coca Cola string. I don't know what to do here...

Comment: @S.Petrosov, Sorry, its because i was translating my code to english. but forgot to change it

Comment: because you're a `noob` does not stop you from googling and reading up on tons of free `C# Basics tutorials and examples`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is just one line of code if you use Linq.

```
public int findWeightByName(string name, Flaske[] kasse)
{
    return kasse.Where(x => x.name == name).Sum(w => w.weight);
}
```

The Where extract a sequence of Flaske with the passed name and Sum acts on the sequence to sum up the Weight

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments, I assume your code should look like this:

```
//Total Bottle Weight
public int findTotalWeight(Flaske[] kasse)
{
        int result = 0;                
        int i = 0;
        while (i < kasse.Length)
        {
            if (kasse[i] != null)
                result = result + kasse[i].weight;
            i = i + 1;
        }
        return result;            
}

//Find Coca Cola Weight
public int findCocaColaWeight(Flaske[] kasse)
{
        int result = 0;                
        int i = 0;
        while (i < kasse.Length)
        {
            if (kasse[i] != null && kasse[i].name.Equals("Coca Cola"))
                result = result + kasse[i].weight;
            i = i + 1;
        }
        return result;            
}
```